# DEPRECATION WARNING: ActionController::TestCase HTTP request methods will accept only keyword arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I keep getting this warning even after I've tried fixing the format to match the example that is given once the test is written as well examples from articles online explaining how to fix the issues. I would like to do this correctly so that I won't have to worry about not testing correctly and also so that I don't get 40 warnings every time I run the full test suite

```
GET example

it "renders the #show view" do
  food = create(:food)
  get :show, params: { id: food.id }
  expect(response).to render_template :show
end

CREATE Example

 it "redirects to user page of user who uploaded food" do
    food_params = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:food)
    post :create, :food => food_params
    expect(response).to redirect_to user_path(@user.id)
  end

SHOW example

it "assigns the requested food to @food" do
  food = create(:food)
  get :show, params: { id: food.id }
  expect(assigns(:food)).to eq(food)
end

DELETE 

 it "deletes the food" do
  expect{ delete :destroy, id: @food}.to change(Food, :count).by(-1)
end

it "redirects to user page of user who deleted food" do
  delete :destroy, id: @food
  expect(response).to redirect_to user_path(@user.id)
end

PUT

it "located the requested @food" do
    put :update, id: @food, food: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:food)
    expect(assigns(:food)).to eq(@food)
  end

  it "changes @food's attributes" do
    put :update, id: @food,
      food: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:food, title: "Yummers", kind: "Salad")
      @food.reload
      expect(@food.title).to eq("Yummers")
      expect(@food.kind).to eq("Salad")
  end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting this from your CREATE Example, where you're passing params in the old style.

Change this:

```
post :create, :food => food_params
```

To this:

```
post :create, params: { food: food_params }
```

Comment: Thank you this worked.. I realized I am having trouble with my put and delete methods as well. I tried following the same pattern but was still getting the warning. I changed them back to their original form to make the tests pass, but can you check out my edit to see what I should change with those?

Comment: `delete :destroy, params: { id: @food.id }` should work. Make sure you change it in both `it` blocks.